# What is the ideal way of sorting Serializable list Java

Tags: java, sorting, generics

I have a `List<? extends Serializable>` which contains an `Integer` list and I want it to be sorted. I can't use the `Collection.sort()` here. There is an exception saying

> The inferred type capture#2-of ? extends Serializable is not a valid
>   substitute for the bounded parameter >

What would be the ideal way ?

Comment: Sorted according to what?

Comment: What would be the condition used for sorting? `Serializable` does not provide any information regarding comparison or sort order.

Comment: **Why** can't you use `Collections.sort()`?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Give us a (approx)  three line code sample that generates the error you've shown us. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If your List contains only Integers why isn't it defined as List<Integer>?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<? extends Serializable> list = Arrays.<Integer> asList(2, 3);
```

Here we're creating a `List<Integer>` but we're *throwing away* the compiler's knowledge that the elements are `Integer`. All the compiler knows about `list` is that it contains elements of type `Serializable`.

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

... won't compile. There is no method called `Collections.sort()` that accepts a single element of any of the types `list` has. There is `Collections.sort(List<?
 extends Comparable>)`, but our `list` doesn't fit this.

However we can use `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` - we just need to supply a `Comparator<? extends Serializable>`.

And that's the problem. There's nothing about `Serializable` that makes sense to compare on. All you can do is an unsafe cast:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(x -> (Integer) x));
```

You know this will work, because you've arranged that `list` actually contains `Integer` -- but casting like this is a code smell. If your class needs its input to be a list of `Integer` then pass in a `List<Integer>`.

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(x -> (Comparable) x));
```

... also works, but has the same smell.

Comment: Well, you can bypass the checking entirely by simply saying `Collections.sort(list, null)` or `list.sort(null)`, stating that the actually contained elements have a natural order, even if the compile-time type doesn’t tell.